# To disallow indexing the category and tag listings in a blog

Tags: seo, links, robots.txt

Mark Wilson says that category and tag listings in a blog should be disallowed in order [to prevent duplicate content](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2007/04/removing-duplicate-search-engine-content-using-robotstxt.htm). I understand this.

However, I want to put internal links on keywords in the blog posts to the tag and category pages in order for the readers to find more relevant content.

I wonder whether putting those internal links to the category/tag pages which are disallowed in robots.txt is counted as useful from the perspective of SEO internal linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359) says

> Google no longer recommends blocking
>   crawler access to duplicate content on
>   your website, whether with a
>   robots.txt file or other methods.

So then I **don't need to disallow** crawling of category/tag listings in my blog. Duplicate content is penalized only when used for malicious purposes:

> In the rare cases in which Google
>   perceives that duplicate content may
>   be shown with intent **to manipulate our
>   rankings** and deceive our users, we'll
>   also make appropriate adjustments in
>   the indexing and ranking of the sites
>   involved. As a result, the ranking of
>   the site may suffer, or the site might
>   be removed entirely from the Google
>   index, in which case it will no longer
>   appear in search results.